# Being started of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am a new comer of Linux. I went into the official website of Linux and it recommends me to use Ubuntu. And I have some questions about Ubuntu.

1. Is Ubuntu free of charge?
2. Now I am using Windows, do I need to have a disk partition?
3. Can I choose rather use Windows or Linux?
4. Can I run Windows applications on Linux?
5. if I want to delete either Linux or Windows, can I restore the two disk partitions back to one?

Comment: How about the version for enterprise or developer? Is it free?

Comment: Its free of charge

Comment: Enterprise and developer versions are also free???

Comment: There are no enterprise or developer versions.

Comment: Note: In the Linux world - *everything* (nearly, excepting RedHat or so) is free in both senses.

Comment: What is the "official website of Linux" you mention?

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, is Ubuntu free of charge?

Yes

> Second, now I am using Windows, do I need to have a disk partition?

In general yes. 
Each installed operating system needs at least its own partition.

Keep in mind: for testing Ubuntu or any other operating system it might make sense to check out a Virtual Machine like Virtualbox, VMware or similar. Great for testing/learning as it reduces the risks for beginners to wreck the core-setup.

> Third, can I choose rather use Windows or Linux?

In case of having several operating systems (which is often called dual Booting) installed you usually have some kind of boot-manager (i.e. grub), which lets you choose which operating system to boot at startup of the computer.

> Fourth, can I run Windows applications on Linux?

In general no, why there are some special cases like using wine to emulate a windows environment. this works for some applications but is no general solution for random window-apps

> Last, if I want to delete either Linux or Windows, can I restore the two disk partitions back to one?

Possible in general yes - depends on what tools you have in access. Modern windows versions can enlarge partitions with inbuild diskmanagement tools, older versions can't.

Comment: So, which Windows versions can restore the two disk partitions back to one?

Comment: From what i know - Windows 7 and above can resize an existing Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ubuntu Operating system is free
2. You will need to partition your hard drive in order to use Ubuntu and Windows on the same computer. 
   [Please see this video for instructions.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU)
3. You can. If you're referring to the same computer, a grub loader will be installed allowing you to choose which operating system you want at start up.
4. You cannot run Windows applications directly on Ubuntu. However you can install Wine which will allow you to run many Windows applications. 
   [Please read here for more.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)
5. Yes, by deleting the Ubuntu partition from Windows will completely remove Ubuntu from your computer. But why would anyone do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ubuntu is completely free of charge.
2. If you want to keep Windows
   **and** run Ubuntu, you will need at least one spare partition (or a new separate disk), and will need to install what is called a
   Dual-Boot system. On the installer you would need to choose the
   option to 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows'. This is not always
   totally straightforward, especially on a UEFI boot based system.
3. If you have installed Dual-Boot, you will choose which system to use
   when the computer starts.
4. Windows applications don't run on Linux. It is possible to use some
   through a few pieces of software, such as Wine or PlayOn Linux, but there are normally bugs, or reduced functionality. Some applications just won't work at all.
5. There are ways to restore your partitions if you remove one of your
   Operating Systems, but you'll need to be comfortable with
   partitioning.

I'd advise making a USB installer for Ubuntu, and selectin the 'Try Ubuntu' option before taking the plunge. Alternatively you could create a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu running on your windows installation through software such as VirtualBox.

P.S. you should only really ask one question at a time on Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

> Second, now I am using Windows, do I need to have a disk partition?

Yes. The Ubuntu installer supports creating partitions, but using it to shrink your Windows partition might be dangerous. I would recommend you use the *Windows Disk Management Utility* that's part of Windows (see [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/shrink-and-extend-ntfs-volumes-in-windows/)). You can then use the installer to create your new partition.

> Third, can I choose rather use Windows or Linux?

Yes. The installer will (normally) install the Grub Boot loader, which will allow you to choose between Windows and Linux.

> Last, if I want to delete either Linux or Windows, can I restore the two disk partitions back to one?

You can, but you first have to delete the Linux partition(s) and then use the *Windows Disk Management Utility* to resize the Windows partition. If you want to get rid of Windows, you can use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) from your Linux installation.

Removing, moving and expanding partitions is dangerous however. You should always make a back-up of all your files, and keep your installation discs ready should anything go wrong.